# i want to make a program to do some usermade functuions like addition and stuff

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <math.h>
using namespace std ; 

int add (float,float);
int Multiply (float,float);
int division (float,float);
int subtract (float,float);


int main ()
{
float x,y,z;
float sum;
float multiply2;
float division2;
float subtract2;

   cout<<"please enter the 3 FLOAT numbers you would like to do the processes on"<<endl;
cin>>x>>y>>z;
 sum = addd(x, y,z);
 cout << "Sum = " << sum;
  return 0;

 multiply2 =  Multiplyy(x, y,z);
 cout << "multiply = " << multiply2;
 return 0;

division2 = divisionn(x, y,z);
cout << "division = " << division2;
return 0;

subtract2 =  subtractt(x, y,z);
cout << "subtract = "<<subtract2 << sum;
return 0;
}

 int addd(float a, float b,float c)
{
float addd;
addd = a + b + c;


return addd;
}

 int Multiplyy(float a, float b,float c)
{
float Multiplyy;
 Multiplyy = a * b * c;


return Multiplyy;
}

 int divisionn(float a, float b,float c)
{
float divisionn;
divisionn = a / b / c;


return divisionn;
}

int subtractt(float a, float b,float c)
 {
float subtractt;
subtractt = a - b -c;


return subtractt;
 }
```

it's not working! it gives me error that identifier is not defined!
so yeah i tried everything i could do, it's very late and i really don't know what i am missing to be honest!
anyhelp would be very good
thanks!

Comment: Tell us what errors you are getting please.

Comment: Please edit your post with the exact error message from the compiler, and also identify which line it is referring to.

Comment: You call `addd`, but only define `add`.  Is this a typo or your real program? Similarly with `Multiplyy` and `Multiply`.

Comment: `Multiplyy` does this look right? The compiler would have complained specifically about it

Comment: i fixed the addd error :) 
now it tells me that all of those 3 funcutions doesn't take 3 arguments

Comment: lines 22,26,30 are those who telll me that the funcution cannot take 3 arguments

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWaelHelaly Because your forward declarations specify that the functions only take two arguments.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forward declarations are incorrect.  You have forward-declared your functions to accept two float arguments, but then your definitions take three arguments.  In addition, the forward-declared function names are not correct (you forward-declare `add`, for example, but then you call and define `addd` later).

Fix your function forward declarations to take `(float, float, float)` instead of `(float, float)`, and name them to match the rest of your program, and [it will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b752fa6779e56d1).

---

You have some other weirdness going on, such as declaring a variable named `addd` within the function `addd` (and in your other functions as well), which is confusing, but will not cause a compile-time error.  This is what I would call a "style bug" -- the program will still run, but the source code is unnecessarily confusing.  Declaring a new identifier that hides a previously-declared identifier is called "shadowing," and as a general rule it should be avoided because it creates confusion.

Your functions also truncate their results, because they accept `float` values but return `int`.  Any fractional part of the computation will be discarded.  (For example, `addd(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)` would be expected to return 4.5, but will instead return 4 because the float-to-int conversion discards the fractional 0.5 component.)